# How to Align Controls to each Other on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, alignment

I'm new to Eclipse and Android and I need to align controls to each other.

In Visual Studio, I can easily align controls and distribute spaces between them. How can I do this in Eclipse?

I got this xml. Just dragged and dropped them to layout. There must be an easy way to align and disstribute. Especially distrubute.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.sbs.MainActivity" >
<!-- Ders adları -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblTurkce"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
    android:text="@string/Turkce" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/lblDil"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblTarih"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_marginBottom="166dp"
      android:text="@string/ingilizce" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/lblMatematik"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblTurkce"
      android:layout_below="@+id/lblTurkce"
      android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
      android:text="@string/Matematik" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/lblFen"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblMatematik"
      android:layout_below="@+id/lblMatematik"
      android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
      android:text="@string/FenveTeknoloji" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/lblTarih"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblFen"
      android:layout_below="@+id/lblFen"
      android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
      android:text="@string/tarih" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/lblDin"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblTarih"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:text="@string/din" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what a friend did and than I started doing too and I can align stuff pretty well.

So ,what you have to do ,is to work with LinearLayouts and their property Orientation property.

Now I don't exactly know what you want to do but I can give you a little example so that you ,hopefully understand what I am writing here.

Let's say you got 3 TextViews and you want to arrange them like two on top of the screen and the last one, you want to be below the two already aligned button.It would look pretty much like a pyramid but with the top being pointed down.

You would do this like that: The first two textViews will be put in a LinearLayout with the Orientation being set to Horizontal (so that the second textView will be in the right of the first textView but on the same line (so aligned to the first textView's right).

Now, the other one won't be necessary to be contained by a LinearLayout ,BUT, the first LinearLayout (with the first and second TextView) and the third textView have to be contained by a LinearLayout that has the Orientation being Vertical.This way the third textView is below the LinearLayout containing the two textViews.

Let me know if you need more explication.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not really what I'm looking for. I'm looking for an easy way to place controls. Check this image, remember these buttons? https://d37wxxhohlp07s.cloudfront.net/s3_images/883747/Smart_Distribute_Tools_inline.jpg

Comment: hmm so what you are looking for are some sort of SeekBar? Or Toggle button?

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout provides various alignment attributes you can use.  For example, if you want to line up the left edges of two different TextViews in your RelativeLayout, you can use the layout_alignLeft attribute like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Text One"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewOne"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textViewOne"
        android:text="Text Two"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that I forced the first TextView to have a left margin and that the second TextView correctly left aligns to the first.  If you take the layout_alignLeft attribute off of the second TextView, it will align to the parent's left edge instead.

Comment: You did it with XML. I have 50 TextView elements. Selected all. Now I need a shortcut or an IDE button to create this xml for me. Do you use Visual Studio? Check the image I've sent above. I know I can write this whole thing and do exactly what I need with xml but I want my IDE do this for me. Any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer for you regarding how to do it with the layout editor in VS.  I've never used one that worked the way I wanted, so I resorted to just editing the XML myself.